How to make a header break into two lines in latex for conference papers?
The conference we are submitting our paper to has a very long line required to be added to the header left aligned. However from the code we are using, the line seems to go through the page without wrapping around for the second line.
We have tried the following code -
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{hhline}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

%%%%%
\makeatletter
 \let\old@ps@headings\ps@headings
 \let\old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle
 \def\confheader#1{%

 % for the first page
 \def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
 \old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle%
 \def\@oddhead{#1\hfill\strut}%
 \def\@evenhead{#1\hfill\strut}%
 }%
 \ps@headings%
 }
 \makeatother

\confheader{%
 2024 3rd International Conference on Advancement in Electrical and Electronic Engineering (ICAEEE), 25-27 April, 2024, Gazipur, Bangladesh
 } 


What I was looking for is Gazipur, Bangladesh to be at the next line in the header.

Please make a compilable [mre]

Replace your existing code with this. I hope it'll work.
\makeatletter
\let\old@ps@headings\ps@headings
\let\old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle
\def\confheader#1{%
 % for the first page
 \def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
 \old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle%
 \def\@oddhead{\strut\hfill\begin{minipage}[b]{1\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}\hfill\strut}%
 \def\@evenhead{\strut\hfill\begin{minipage}[b]{1\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}\hfill\strut}%
 }%
 \ps@headings%
}
\makeatother

\confheader{%
 2024 3rd International Conference on Advancement in Electrical and Electronic Engineering (ICAEEE),  25-27 April, 2024, Gazipur, Bangladesh
 }

